# Simplifying an integral arising in Physical Chemistry

Tags: analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, physics

I am struggling to understand the following transition (encountered in a paper on Physical Chemistry).

Let
$$D=\frac{\tau_0^{-1}\int_0^\infty G(t)dt}{1-\tau_0^{-1}\int_0^\infty G(t)\int w(R)\exp[-tw(R)] d^3R dt},\qquad (1)$$
where
$$G(t)= \exp\left\{-\frac{t}{\tau_0}-n\int (1-e^{-tw(R)})dR-n_A\int (1-e^{-tu(R)})dR \right\},$$
$$w(R)=\frac{1}{\tau_0}\left(\frac{R_0}{R}\right)^6,\qquad u(R)=\frac{1}{\tau_0}\left(\frac{R_A}{R}\right)^6.$$
The authors claim that
$$\qquad\qquad\quad\qquad D=\frac{1-f(y)}{1-\frac{c}{c+c_A}f(y)}.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(2)$$
Here $$f(y)=\sqrt{\pi} y\exp(y^2)\left[1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^y\exp(-t^2)dt\right],$$
$$y=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}(c+c_A),$$
$$c=\frac{4\pi}{3}R_0^3n,\qquad c_A=\frac{4\pi}{3}R_A^3n_A.$$

**Question.** How does one pass from (1) to (2)?

Comment: Could you please share the link of the paper?